# How do I use RSA keys generated by Java in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, rsa, public-key

I'm having a problem in loading **RSA public key** that was generated by **Java** in **Ruby**.

The RSA public key was encoded in X509 format by Java. FYI, here's the Java code for generating the public key

```
public static void generateKeys() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    System.out.println("keys created");

    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,
            RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(privateKey,
            RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

    saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(), pub.getPublicExponent());
    saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(), priv.getPrivateExponent());

    System.out.println("keys saved");
}

public static void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod,
        BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    try {
        fileOut.writeObject(mod);
        fileOut.writeObject(exp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected error");
    } finally {
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Closed writing file.");
    }
}
```

I've tried using the public.key in my Ruby by using :

```
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'public.key' and
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read 'public.key'
```

But none of them work, instead they printed out error message :

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError:
  Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: header too long
OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError:
  header too long
```

I'm planning to use the **public.key** to **encrypt some data in Ruby**. Can anyone help me out? I really appreciate one, thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to *expect* that Ruby can read in a serialized Java object? No. Find some commonly supported formats. Most likely to succeed would be the getEncoded() methods of the PublicKey and PrivateKey classes which return SubjectPublicKeyInfo and PrivateKeyInfo ASN.1 objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried using the PublicKey.getEncoded() and it returns byte value, which is [B@1d9d565, but I need RSA keys in base64 format like this :
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
<Base 64 format public key here>
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
How could I get that format?

Comment: Use the getEncoded() result, encode it using base64 and do some string concat...